# log4j config.properties file configuration example

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, properties-file

Hi guys just want to share how to configure your log4j.properties file
note that the # is commented out line

FATAL: shows messages at a FATAL level only

ERROR: Shows messages classified as ERROR and FATAL

WARNING: Shows messages classified as WARNING, ERROR, and FATAL

INFO: Shows messages classified as INFO, WARNING, ERROR, and FATAL

DEBUG: Shows messages classified as DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, and FATAL

TRACE : Shows messages classified as TRACE,DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, and FATAL

ALL : Shows messages classified as TRACE,DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, and FATAL

OFF : No log messages display

```
log4j.rootLogger= INFO, file, console
#Level/rules TRACE < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL.

#######################################
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=ALL
log4j.appender.file.file=logs/myFol.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n

# set file size limit
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=50


#############################################
# Direct log messages to System Out
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %L - %m%n
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %c{1}: %m%n
#log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %M:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: is this a question or are you sharing?

Comment: Hi @FarhanQasim, sorry i was not very clear, I'm actually **sharing the knowledge** because recently I found my self a bit struggle to find examples with it so worth to share :-) , so **if you use the code above will work** best regards

Comment: @Philippe since you are sharing you should answer your own question